# Package the smart contract :Fatal error when initializing core config

Tags: contract

I followed the order of the official docs v:release-2.2.
when I create the chaincode package using the peer lifecycle chaincode package command:

```
peer lifecycle chaincode package basic.tar.gz --path ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go/ --lang golang --label basic_1.0
```

in test-network directory.

ERRO 001 Fatal error when initializing core config : Could not find config file. Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH is set to a path which contains core.yaml

And I execute the command 'echo $FABRIC_CFG_PATH' to view the path and enter the path below ,but I already have configtx.yaml core.yaml ordererer.yaml file under my FABRIC_CFG_PATH, How can I solve it?Look forward to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to change my `$FABRIC_CFG_PATH` to be an absolute path, not a relative path...

That is:
`~/go/src/github.com/username/fabric-samples/config` didn't work,

but... `/home/username/go/src/github.com/username/fabric-samples/config` did